# Multiple table inheritance in Laravel 5.2

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2. I have many models in my application i.e. User, Lawyer, Manager, etc.

I am extending Lawyer and Manager model from the base User model.

```
    class LawyerController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function index()
    {
        $lawyer = Lawyer::findOrFail(1);
        return $lawyer->name;
    }
}
```

The return statement is sending null.

Shouldn't the line `$lawyer->name` pick the name from base class? What is wrong there? And is it possible to make multiple table inheritance in this manner?

Comment: How is the underlying database organized?  Do you have a master user table, and then separate tables for each subtype?

Comment: Yes, I have a master table and separate tables for subtype

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made multitable Inheritance work in Eloquent:

Morph over Model inheritance, Model inheritance in multi-table has proved to be very inefficient based on my experience with Doctrine

This is my morphMap configuration

```
Relation::morphMap([
    2 => Flight::class,
    1 => Boat::class
], false);
/* The 'false' as second parameter is to indicate Eloquent that it has to use this map and nothing else, otherwise it will merge this map with what it gets from metadata and make a mess with that. I use this ints for the types because they are FKs of the table with all the types that I use to list in a Drop Down so the user can select what he wants to create */

class Sequence{
    /* Second parameter indicates the discriminator column name, that will be the column with the value indicating the type of the sublcass (1:B, 2:C) as mapped in morphMap and the third parameter indicates the key value of the sublcass (not FK_CONSTRAINT because it could be from Class B or C) */

    public function sequencable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo("sequencable","sequencable_type_id", "sequencable_id");
    }
}

Class Boat{
    public function sequence(){
        return $this->morphOne('Models\Sequence','sequencable');
    }
}

Class Flight{
    public function sequence(){
        return $this->morphOne('Models\Sequence','sequencable');
    }
}
```

Now to use this, I wrote something like:

```
$type = 2; //You get this from the request or whatever logic you have
$sequence= new Travel\Sequence()();
$model = $sequence->sequencable()->createModelByType($type);
$model->save();
$sequence->sequencable()->associate($model);
$sequence->save();
```

The method **createModelByType($type)** is a helpful thing to use.

The Sequence table looks something like this:

```
//sequencable_type_id indicates the type of the sublcass
//sequencable_id indicates the type of the sublcass
{id,sequencable_type_id, sequencable_id}
```

The subclass looks like this

```
{id,column1, column2, etc...}
```

Comment: this is polymorphic approach, not multi-class table inheritance (https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)

Comment: but where should I define this `Relation::morphMap`?

Comment: Anywhere but you can skip that and use a string sequencable_type instead of sequencable_type_id, Laravel will use the class name as sequencable_type, and Yosua is right, this is polymorphic and not inheritance